# Mysql Case, Then and Compare values

Tags: mysql

My query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.merchant = 'apple' THEN ( a.price / 0.9 ) * 0.8 ELSE a.price END AS 'price', a.*, b.* FROM products a JOIN data b on ( a.post_id = b.post_id ) AND a.price BETWEEN 0 AND 4 ORDER BY a.score DESC LIMIT 0, 11
```

My querstion is, how to change the query so that the new discounted price (after CASE function) is compared in (BETWEEN) function.

Currently BETWEEN function compare old price.

Comment: You can not use a column alias in the WHERE clause, so you will either have to simply repeat this whole CASE statement in your WHERE clause - or use HAVING for that part instead. (But be aware that the latter can have performance implications.)

Comment: Assuming there is only one column named `score`, try; `SELECT * FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN a.merchant = 'apple' THEN ( a.price / 0.9 ) * 0.8 ELSE a.price END AS 'the_price', a.*, b.* FROM products a JOIN data b on ( a.post_id = b.post_id )) sq WHERE sq.the_price BETWEEN 0 AND 4 ORDER BY sq.score DESC LIMIT 0, 11`. Otherwise, you will have two columns named `price`.